# How do I intercept a method inside a function component using jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm looking for a way to mock/override a function definition inside a function component on my jest test, see the below snippet for clarification:

```js
function myComponent(){
   // the method 'someMethodInMyComponent' is the method I want to mock
  function someMethodInMyComponent() {
    return 'hello world'
  }
  return <p>{someMethodInMyComponent}</p>
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Is it possible? I've read through the docs but can't seem to find anything on this scenario. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, that's not possible - that function only exists inside an invocation of myComponent. It's just an implementation detail - test the right result gets rendered.

Comment: It is not possible, but you can mock the content inside someMethodInMyComponent , for example if you are using fetch to get some data

Comment: thanks for the help, indeed the contents of someMethoInMyComponent is a fetch, in this case, how could I mock its content?